# Query returning the same row multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query is returning one result multiple times. I know the answer has to be simple, but I'm stumped. Any help is appreciated.

My code is below.

```
USE ODS

DECLARE @recalctime AS TIME
DECLARE @portfolio AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @loannumber AS BIGINT
DECLARE @zipcode AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @timezone AS VARCHAR(10)
DECLARE @calltime AS TIME
DECLARE @cst AS DATETIME
DECLARE @calldate AS DATETIME

SELECT
@portfolio = CASE
    WHEN r.PortfolioID = '10' THEN 'A'
    WHEN r.portfolioid = '11' THEN 'B'
    WHEN r.PortfolioID = '12' THEN 'C'
    ELSE CAST(r.portfolioid AS VARCHAR)
    END 
, @calldate = CAST(r.RowCreatedDate AS DATE) 
, @loannumber = r.loannumber 
, @zipcode = r.zipcode 
, @timezone = r.zone 
, @calltime = CONVERT(char(10), r.contacttime, 108) 
, @recalctime = CASE
    WHEN r.Zone = 'PST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -3, r.contacttime)
    WHEN r.Zone = 'CST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, r.contacttime)
    WHEN r.Zone = 'EST' THEN r.contacttime
    WHEN r.Zone = 'MST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -2, r.contacttime)
    ELSE CONVERT(char(10), r.contacttime, 108)
    END 

FROM dbo.table r (nolock)


SELECT 
@portfolio AS 'Product'
, @loannumber AS 'Loan Number'
, CAST(@calldate AS DATE) AS 'Call Date'
, @zipcode AS 'Zip Code'
, CONVERT(char(10), @calltime, 108) AS 'Timezone'
, CONVERT(char(10), @recalctime, 108) AS 'Call Time'
, DATEPART(hh, @recalctime)
, @timezone AS 'Recalc Time'

FROM dbo.table r (nolock)
```

I'm getting 89,928 rows of the same result.

Comment: Change `FROM dbo.table r` in the second query to `FROM DUAL`. You just want to return the values of the variables once, not once for each row in the table.

Comment: Not sure how the top query ran successfully if your table has 89K rows as you don't seem to have a WHERE clause, but for the bottom query, remove the `FROM` clause completely, to select just the variables.

Comment: I do not believe `FROM Dual` is SQL Server.  Or at least not SQL 2012 and prior.

Answer (score 2):

Your first query will perform local var assignment for each row in the table, rewriting this value for every row, and ending up holding values derived from the last row. Your second query returns those values as many times as there are rows.

If you just want to output your derived values, combine these two queries into one, and don't use local variables at all.

Answer (score 1):

The first query is assigning the variables per row which might not be what you are trying to do.

In general, most uses of the first query would include a where clause so the values would be from a specific row:

```
SELECT
@portfolio = CASE
    WHEN r.PortfolioID = '10' THEN 'A'
    WHEN r.portfolioid = '11' THEN 'B'
    WHEN r.PortfolioID = '12' THEN 'C'
    ELSE CAST(r.portfolioid AS VARCHAR)
    END 
, @calldate = CAST(r.RowCreatedDate AS DATE) 
, @loannumber = r.loannumber 
, @zipcode = r.zipcode 
, @timezone = r.zone 
, @calltime = CONVERT(char(10), r.contacttime, 108) 
, @recalctime = CASE
    WHEN r.Zone = 'PST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -3, r.contacttime)
    WHEN r.Zone = 'CST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, r.contacttime)
    WHEN r.Zone = 'EST' THEN r.contacttime
    WHEN r.Zone = 'MST' THEN DATEADD(HOUR, -2, r.contacttime)
    ELSE CONVERT(char(10), r.contacttime, 108)
    END 

FROM dbo.table r (nolock)
WHERE [MyColumn] = something
```

There is no need in the second query for the "from dbo.table" as this will select out the variables per record in the table.

```
 SELECT 
    @portfolio AS 'Product'
    , @loannumber AS 'Loan Number'
    , CAST(@calldate AS DATE) AS 'Call Date'
    , @zipcode AS 'Zip Code'
    , CONVERT(char(10), @calltime, 108) AS 'Timezone'
    , CONVERT(char(10), @recalctime, 108) AS 'Call Time'
    , DATEPART(hh, @recalctime)
    , @timezone AS 'Recalc Time'
```

;

If you don't use the variables for anything else you can combine it all together in a single query:

```
SELECT
    [Product] = CASE
        WHEN r.PortfolioID = '10' THEN 'A'
        WHEN r.portfolioid = '11' THEN 'B'
        WHEN r.PortfolioID = '12' THEN 'C'
        ELSE CAST(r.portfolioid AS VARCHAR)
        END 
   -- Note you can also use the 'AS' syntax depending on version of sql server
    , CAST(r.RowCreatedDate AS DATE) AS 'Call Date'
    ...etc        
    FROM dbo.table r (nolock)
    WHERE [MyColumn] = something
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in table  "dbo.table" have total 89,928 rows, That is the reason it shows 89,928 times.

you need to select only Variables

```
SELECT 
@portfolio AS 'Product'
, @loannumber AS 'Loan Number'
, CAST(@calldate AS DATE) AS 'Call Date'
, @zipcode AS 'Zip Code'
, CONVERT(char(10), @calltime, 108) AS 'Timezone'
, CONVERT(char(10), @recalctime, 108) AS 'Call Time'
, DATEPART(hh, @recalctime)
, @timezone AS 'Recalc Time'
```